# Hibernate entity 'patch' /partial update

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

In hibernate, I want to update an existing entity with 'half' an entity as passed from a rest api call with `PATCH`.

So here, `HalfEntity` would be a pojo with getters and setters based on what the rest api user is allowed to send, which would be a subset of `Entity`.

Is there a fastest way to assign the entity with the new values in the 'half' of an entity?

So as oppposed to writing a load of this...

```
Entity.setValue(HalfEntity.getValue());
Entity.setValue2(HalfEntity.getValue2());
Entity.setValue3(HalfEntity.getValue3());
Entity.setValue5(HalfEntity.getValue5());
```

...I want to write this:

```
Entity.patch(HalfEntity);
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
public void patch(Object halfEntity) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException{
    for(Field f:halfEntity.getClass().getDeclaredFields()){
        f.setAccessible(true);
        f.set(this, f.get(halfEntity));
    }
}
```

Comment: and if the persistence solution is using bytecode enhancement then that is thrown away.